# AWS c++ SDK Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::CognitoIdentityProviderClient InitiateAuth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to initiate Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::CognitoIdentityProviderClient InitiateAuth

Here is my code:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
clientConfiguration.region = regionId;
clientConfiguration.proxyHost = "<>";
clientConfiguration.proxyPort = <>;
clientConfiguration.proxyScheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTP;

Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Model::InitiateAuthRequest authRequest;
authRequest.SetAuthFlow(Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Model::AuthFlowType::USER_SRP_AUTH);
authRequest.SetClientId(clientId);
authParameters.insert(std::make_pair("USERNAME", userName));
authParameters.insert(std::make_pair("SRP_A", srp_A));
authRequest.SetAuthParameters(authParameters);

std::shared_ptr<Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::CognitoIdentityProviderClient>  cognitoClient = std::make_shared<Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::CognitoIdentityProviderClient>(clientConfiguration);

auto authRequestResult = cognitoClient->InitiateAuth(authRequest);
```

Here is what I get in the Trace logs:

[TRACE] 2018-10-24 14:02:16 CurlHttpClient [140737353963648] content-length: 935
[TRACE] 2018-10-24 14:02:16 CurlHttpClient [140737353963648] content-type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
[TRACE] 2018-10-24 14:02:16 CurlHttpClient [140737353963648] host: cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
[TRACE] 2018-10-24 14:02:16 CurlHttpClient [140737353963648] user-agent: aws-sdk-cpp/1.6.30 Linux/3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64 GCC/4.8.5
[TRACE] 2018-10-24 14:02:16 CurlHttpClient [140737353963648] x-amz-target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth
[DEBUG] 2018-10-24 14:02:26 CURL [140737353963648] (HeaderIn) HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

I have managed to debug and I think that behind the scene the code is executing an equivalent of:
curl -i \
    -H "transfer-encoding:" \
    -H "content-length: 914" \
    -H "content-type: application/x-amz-json-1.1" \
    -H "host: cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "user-agent: aws-sdk-cpp/1.6.30 Linux/3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64 GCC/4.8.5" \
    -H "x-amz-target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth" \
    -X POST \
    -d '{"AuthFlow":"USER_SRP_AUTH","AuthParameters":{"SRP_A":"<>","USERNAME":"<>"},"ClientId":"<>"}' \
    https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com --verbose --proxy http://proxy:port

I do not know why it does not work ? Proxy or wrong setup in the code?

Please help.